# Is it possible to setup Lightning Network Nostr tipping using Bolt12 offers?

Tags: lightning-network, core-lightning, bolt12-offers

I see that [NIP-57](https://github.com/nostr-protocol/nips/blob/master/57.md) references / depends on the LNURL specification, which references [LUD-06](https://github.com/lnurl/luds/blob/luds/06.md) and [LUD-16](https://github.com/lnurl/luds/blob/luds/16.md).

As someone still rather new to all the various specifications, can somebody explain to me in simple terms if it is possible to integrate a Bolt12 invoice with LUD-06 or LUD-16 identifiers, and consequently, Nostr tipping?

Bolt12 seems to me like a clean solution without necessitating an intermediary web server. What needs to be done in order to get Nostr tipping using Bolt12? Another NIP?

Thanks in advance for any help putting these pieces of understanding together.

Comment: What would be the use case? You can already have user-defined amounts with NIP-57 and bolt11. What would a Bolt12 offer add here?

Comment: @RainerFeike As stated, I would like to see p2p tipping over NOSTR without the need for an intermediary web server required by LNURL. There should be more Bolt12 standardization across lightning network implementations in general, but I think NOSTR tipping is a great use case for moving in that direction.

Answer (score 0):

> Bolt12 seems to me like a clean solution without necessitating an intermediary web server. What needs to be done in order to get Nostr tipping using Bolt12? Another NIP?

Yes it is.

> I see that NIP-57 references / depends on the LNURL specification, which references LUD-06 and LUD-16.

I am not following the nostr protocol but I think it is possible to make an alternative version. I am not sure if it is possible to alternate the NIP a little bit to support bolt12 in it.

Happy to see something around